# Verification - Are the intersections/unions of these sets convex/compact/bounded?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I'm looking to see if I have found the correct answers to these questions.

Define for $a, b \in \mathbb{R^{2}}, d>0, r>0  $ the sets $V_{a;d} = \{x \in \mathbb{R^{2}}:\max\{|x_{1}-a_{1}|, |x_{2}-a_{2}|\} < d \} $ and $W_{b;r} = \{x \in \mathbb{R^{2}}: ||x - b|| \le r\}$.

Let $a = (0,0), b = (0,0), d = r = 1 $.

a) Is $ V_{a;d} \cap W_{b;r}$ convex? Is it compact? Is $ V_{a;d} \cup W_{b;r}$ convex? Is it open? Is it compact?

Let $a = (0,0), b = (1,1), r = 1 $.

b) Is $ V_{a;d} \cap W_{b;r}$ convex for all $d>0$?

Give all values of $d$ such that $ V_{a;d} \cap W_{b;r}$ is compact. Give all values of $d$ such that $ V_{a;d} \cap W_{b;r}$ is not compact.

I've added my proposed answers as an answer. If this kind of question is not allowed, should be posted in a different format or there's an easy way for me to verify my own solutions in the future, please say so.

Answer (score 1):

a) Since both V and W are convex, its intersection is convex. Since the intersection is not closed (the boundary has 2 "holes" in it at (0,1) and (1,0)), the intersection is not compact. The union is convex. The union is not closed (it contains the points (1,0) and (0,1) which are not interior points).The union is not bounded, nor is it closed, hence it is not compact

b) For all $d>0$, V is a convex set. Since W is also a convex set, its intersection is a convex set for all $d > 0$. The only intersection of the two sets which is closed is obtained when it equals the empty set. Hence, for $d \le 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt2} $ (which is where the intersection equals the empty set), the intersection is compact (since the empty set is compact). For all $d > 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$, the intersection is not closed and hence not compact.